# Victorlaerte AsyncTask libray error during maven compile in JavaFX program

Tags: javafx, build, android-asynctask, maven-3, exe

I have problem with a build native build and compilation application by maven. I cant solve error:

> package com.victorlaerte.asynctask does not exist

i dont know how to deal with it, libray is added by maven and working properly when i run program by intelij.

[image: libs screen]

**compile errors:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project PROJECT_NAME: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/xxxx/dir/APP_NAME/src/main/java/api/request/UpdateDownload.java:[6,34] package com.victorlaerte.asynctask does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/xxxx/dir/APP_NAME/src/main/java/api/request/UpdateDownload.java:[18,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class AsyncTask
[ERROR] /C:/Users/xxxx/dir/APP_NAME/src/main/java/api/request/LicenseCheckStatus.java:[5,34] package com.victorlaerte.asynctask does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/xxxx/dir/APP_NAME/src/main/java/api/request/LicenseCheckStatus.java:[17,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class AsyncTask
[ERROR] /C:/Users/xxxx/dir/APP_NAME/src/main/java/controller/PreloaderWindowController.java:[4,34] package com.victorlaerte.asynctask does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/xxxx/dir/APP_NAME/src/main/java/api/request/LicenseRegister.java:[7,34] package com.victorlaerte.asynctask does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/xxxx/dir/APP_NAME/src/main/java/api/request/LicenseRegister.java:[19,38] cannot find symbol
```

Comment: Can you share your pom file?

Comment: i cant paste it here, please look at gist:https://gist.github.com/PawelSzymanski89/e3c91a0033b984e9176c0c366b8c9eee

Comment: where are you declaring the jfx-asynctask dependency? I can't see it in your pom.xml

Comment: thanks.... its working now i just removed libray from import by project structure and add direct by pom and everything is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pom.xml works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.victorlaerte</groupId>
    <artifactId>asynctask</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.victorlaerte</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfx-asynctask</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Java:

```
import com.victorlaerte.asynctask.AsyncTask;

public class Test extends AsyncTask {

    public void onPreExecute() {

    }

    public Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Object o) {

    }

    public void progressCallback(Object[] objects) {

    }
}
```